# How to define sub types of functions in python?

Tags: python-2.7, function

I would like to have a way to mark a function as some type, for example, define a function type that when called automatically calls it twice. There is a similar system in Unitys networking tools to mark methods as **[Command]** or **[ClientRpc]** where a method marked **[ClientRpc]** is called on all clients and **[Command]** is only called on the server.

Comment: Read about decorators

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for :)